# generics vs inheritance in mvc controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, inheritance, controllers

We have a number of controllers with very similar functionality, there is a lot of code duplication. There are base controllers which contain some code that is used in all of them however most is still duplicated. Each controller has a constructor, the services are being injected by castle.

I was thinking would it be possible to use generics with controllers to reduce the amount of duplication. Have the similar code in a base class and override any instances where the code deviates.

Alternatively I you could do the same without generics and have more of the duplicate code in the base.

What would be the best approach and how would generics be implemented in controllers? I'm guessing they would make use of interfaces as well.

Comment: How about factories and services for the duplicate code? Or is that already implemented, but still there's duplicate code? Otherwise, I would use both a base controller class and generics if there was a purpose for it.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give answer without looking at the application. But, Generics is useful to write reusable code across different types.

```
public class Stack<T>
{
  T[] m_Items; 
  public void Push(T item) {...}
  public T Pop() {...}
}
Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
stack.Push(1);
stack.Push(2);
int number = stack.Pop();
```

There is a type safety with generics. It is insured that `Push` will accept `int` and `Pop` will return `int`. Similarly, you can use the it for `string` etc.. Otherwise, you've to use the `object` in which case there is no gurantee for type.